# How to delete a User with particular email using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am following the quick Quick Start Tutorial(http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#quickstart) Its possible to create/delete/update a user in database if we know its "id", But is it possible to do the same for a user with particular email ?
Please also suggest the modifications needed to make this possible and enable API to lookup by email like users/email.

Comment: Query the database for a user whos email matches the email you want to delete and use the reference that the query returns to delete the entity

Comment: Check out the docs for Django, there'll be all you need to know. Look up terms like `django filter queryset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` on your view or viewset that subclasses `GenericAPIView`. A basic example using a `ModelViewSet` and a `SimpleRouter` would look like this:

views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'email'
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'^users', UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`, you must set `lookup_field` in the serializer too.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username')
        lookup_field = 'email'
```